# using Gradle, Apache cxf WSDLToJava generated source code will not compile - missing jakarta packages but dependecies have been referenced

Tags: java, gradle, cxf, java-11

Jakarta packages are not found when the generated Java is compiled.
Jakarta dependencies are referenced in build.gradle for the module:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}
configurations {
    wsdl2java
}

dependencies {
    wsdl2java 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0'
    wsdl2java 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-ri:4.0.2'
    wsdl2java 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:4.0.2'
    wsdl2java 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:4.0.2'
    wsdl2java 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:4.0.2'
    wsdl2java 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-core:4.0.0'
    wsdl2java 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws:4.0.0'
    wsdl2java 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-databinding-jaxb:4.0.0'
}
```

Gradle to generate the code includes

```
classpath configurations.wsdl2java
```

Resulting example code includes imports that do not resolve

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
```

When the task attempts to compile, error is:

```
error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
```

Yet, all these are supposed to be included in

```
jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0
```

Full build.gradle file is:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}
configurations {
    wsdl2java
}

dependencies {
    wsdl2java 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0'
    wsdl2java 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-ri:4.0.2'
    wsdl2java 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:4.0.2'
    wsdl2java 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:4.0.2'
    wsdl2java 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:4.0.2'
    wsdl2java 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-core:4.0.0'
    wsdl2java 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws:4.0.0'
    wsdl2java 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-databinding-jaxb:4.0.0'
}

def allmyWsdl = task allmyWsdl {
    String[] wsdls = ["one", "two", "three"];

    wsdls.each {name->
        def thing = task "myWsdl${name}" (type: JavaExec) {
            // Defining these mean the task can run incrementally
            inputs.files("${projectDir}/src/main/resources")
            outputs.dir("${projectDir}/out/generated-sources/cxf-ws")

            String wsdl = "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/wsdls/${name}.wsdl"
            String genSrcDir = "${projectDir}/out/generated-sources/cxf-ws"

            inputs.file wsdl
            outputs.dir genSrcDir

            classpath configurations.wsdl2java
            main "org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava"

            args '-client', '-impl', '-exsh', 'true', '-noAddressBinding', '-autoNameResolution', "-wsdlLocation", "classpath:wsdls/${name}.wsdl", '-p', "com.my.webservices.${name}", '-encoding', 'UTF-8', '-d', genSrcDir, wsdl

            final OutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
            errorOutput = new OutputStream() {
                void write(int b) {System.err.write(b); baos.write(b) }
                void flush() { System.err.flush(); baos.flush() }
                void close() { System.err.close(); baos.close() }
            }

            doLast {
                def str = baos.toString()
                if (str.contains('Usage : wsdl2java') || str.contains('WSDLToJava Error')) {
                    throw new TaskExecutionException(tasks[name],
                            new IOException('Apache CXF WSDLToJava has failed. Please see System.err output.'))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

allmyWsdl.dependsOn(tasks.matching { task -> task.name.startsWith( 'myWsdl' ) } )
compileJava.dependsOn += allmyWsdl
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += 'out/generated-sources/cxf-ws'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that while generating java from wsdl you are adding all libraries to classpath `classpath configurations.wsdl2java`. But while compiling those libraries are not in the classpath so you get those errors.

You need to adjust `dependencies` section as follow.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0'
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:4.0.0'
    wsdl2java 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-ri:4.0.2'
    wsdl2java 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:4.0.2'
    wsdl2java 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:4.0.2'
    wsdl2java 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:4.0.2'
    wsdl2java 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-core:4.0.0'
    wsdl2java 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws:4.0.0'
    wsdl2java 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-databinding-jaxb:4.0.0'
}
```

As `jakarta.xml.bind-api` and `jakarta.xml.ws-api` libraries don't need while generating java classes. But those are required while compiling. So added those 2 as implementation dependencies which adds to Java compile and runtime classpaths.

Comment: Doh! Many thanks  stackoverflow beats chatgpt :)